# Does everything have to be a polygon in openGL (java)?

Tags: java, jogl, sprite, texture-mapping, polygons

I am extremely new to JOGL, and I have two main questions about JOGL, the first is about sprites and animations and the next is about textures.

(I am not doing 3d, this is all in the contexts of 2d)

1.) I have been able to create quads, polygons, and so forth in JOGL, but I am very curious, is that the only way to get a type of image that you can manipulate out there? For instance if you want a sprite of a man to appear in JOGL, and when you move the sprite it will move in the direction you make it but also display an animation. Is there a way to do this efficiently in JOGL, or do I have to scalp a shape out of polygons, one vertex at a time, and then paint a texture over it? Or is there a simpler method of just loading the sprite and displaying it right then and there and of course changing the image depending on user input. If there is a way to do it without creating a vertex for every corner of the sprite could you display some code, or a tutorial so I can grasp the idea of what you are doing.

2.) I have been searching around for a way of displaying textures in JOGL, but I am still confused on how to do so. Let me first show you the way I found of loading and display a texture on a shape. First I create 7 variables:

```
Texture image;
private String textureFileName = "images/crate.png";
private String textureFileType = ".png";
private float textureTop, textureBottom, textureLeft, textureRight;
```

Next in my init() method I load my image by doing the following:

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); 
gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
image = TextureIO.newTexture(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(textureFileName),false, textureFileType);
// Use linear filter for texture if image is larger than the original texture
gl.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// Use linear filter for texture if image is smaller than the original texture
gl.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
TextureCoords textureCoords = image.getImageTexCoords();
textureTop = textureCoords.top();
textureBottom = textureCoords.bottom();
textureLeft = textureCoords.left();
textureRight = textureCoords.right();
```

Then in the display method I do the following

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
image.enable(gl);
image.bind(gl);
gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS);
gl.glTexCoord2f(textureLeft,textureTop);
gl.glVertex2d(c,a); // vertex 1
gl.glTexCoord2f(textureLeft, textureBottom);
gl.glVertex2d(c,b); // vertex 2
gl.glTexCoord2f(textureRight, textureBottom);
gl.glVertex2d(d,b); // vertex 3
gl.glTexCoord2f(textureRight, textureTop);
gl.glVertex2d(d,a); // vertex 4
gl.glEnd();
//Variables a,b,c,d are just doubles with certain values for each point
```

Now I just wish to know if this is an effective way to load images and display them if I am going to be having multiple textures. Seeing this way I have devised a plan on how to do that using this method but I want to know if this is the best way of doing it. I have see people talk about **bmp loaders** but hearing of what they do, mapping everything single integer value the image has, seems really complex. Is there no simple way to do it? But if not could someone show me how or point me into a direction of the most correct, and efficient way to load textures and display those textures.

One last thing, when I put the line:

```
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Isnt this just basically just clearing out an integers for pixels, etc. in the buffer? But what does the **|** do anyways? Does it shift the bits?

Also what do these two lines of code do? Im confused by the comments. These two lines appear in my init() method for loading a texture:

```
// Use linear filter for texture if image is larger than the original texture
gl.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// Use linear filter for texture if image is smaller than the original texture
gl.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Thank you for taking the time to read and respond to this message, Thank you.

-Dan

Comment: Usually with sprites, you draw a quad or two triangles and give them a texture. If you want to animate it, you move the quad and use a different texture.  This is all 2D sprite-based stuff. It's different if you're drawing complex 3D models.

Comment: Hi Dan, take a look to this small [sample](https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/modern-jogl-examples/src/tut14/basicTexture/BasicTexture.java)